# Cargo not running tests in top-level file

Tags: unit-testing, module, rust, rust-cargo

I'm quite confused by how Cargo finds tests to run.

I've created a Cargo project and it added a `main.rs` for me. If I add `#[test]` functions in there, they're found and run with `cargo test`. If I add a `foo.rs` file as a sibling to `main.rs` and add tests in there, they're not found and run.

What subtlety am I missing? Do I somehow have to teach Cargo about new files?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Cargo will not just compile any files that happen to be in your source directory. In order for Cargo to find a file, it must be referenced as a module either in `main.rs`/`lib.rs` or from some sub-module.

For example, in your `main.rs`:

```
mod foo;
```

That's it.

Comment: Would you idiomatically put unit tests in their own file, and have prod mode mod them in? Or just put the tests in the file of the thing under test?

Comment: Does anyone find this behaviour weird or is it just me?

Comment: @Afaq I found it confusing at first because it's different to languages that I'm used to. But it doesn't seem strange to me now. It's an entirely logical approach, just with a different set of tradeoffs from, say, Java.

Comment: @PeterHall Yes, it is a bit confusing. Although, I found this very interesting blog about organising tests in Rust http://sireliah.com/niusy/testing_in_rust/